# Spring MVC 4 multi-select

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jsp-tags

I am getting an 400 Error - Bad Request

Type Status Report

Description The server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).

the problem is coming from:

```
<form:select path="children" multiple="multiple">
    <form:options items="${animals}" itemValue="key" itemLabel="name"/>
</form:select>
```

Here is the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveAnimal", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView saveAnimal(@ModelAttribute Animal animal,HttpServletRequest request) {
        if(animal.getKey() == null) {
            animalService.addAnimal(animal);
        }
        else animalService.updateAnimal(animal);

    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/animals");
}
```

I am no sure how to retrieve the values form the multiple select. Everything works fine without this field. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your form:

```
<form:select path="children" multiple="true">
    <form:options items="${animals}" itemValue="key" itemLabel="name"/>
</form:select>
```